# Drawer Widget In Flutter

Tags: flutter, error-handling, navigation, sidebar, drawer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvErV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc7rr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGw6O.png)

When i am trying to use drawer without app bar i am taking this error.

error: The method 'openDrawer' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

I tried bunch of solutions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`, if you are putting it in the same widget use `Builder`.

````
child: Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(
        CupertinoIcons.text_alignleft,
        size: 30,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
    );
  },
),
    ```
````

Comment: I am new in flutter so i don't know where to put Builder can you explain more deatily.

Comment: sure, put the example of the code and I'll show you

Comment: Here is my side bar button:  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.79),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.text_alignleft, size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
                      onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                    ),
                  ),

Comment: GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();                 
 key: _scaffoldKey,